# You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, disk-usage

When I try to install new programs, I'm having this error:

```
You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

How can I increase space in the folder?

Answer (score 3):

Run `apt autoclean`: this will remove archives you no longer need. If that’s not sufficient, `apt clean` will remove all the archives; if necessary, they will be downloaded again in the future.

Comment: can't i increase the folder size?

Comment: That's not how it works. Directories don't have their own size limits. The error actually means the *filesystem* the directory resides in doesn't have enough space left. It's like a room in a house: if you fill it up to where there's no space left to put more stuff in, you can't make the room (or a box in the room) bigger; you can only take stuff out. (Note: yes, there are setups where you actually *can* allocate more space to certain filesystems, but that most likely doesn't apply here.)

Answer (score 0):

If

```
apt autoclean
```

and

```
apt clean
```

do not help you can just upgrade the packages one after another with:

```
apt install <packagename> --fix-missing
```

You have to do it for at least some packages from the list provided by `apt upgrade`.

After some packages are upgraded try again with:

```
apt clean
apt upgrade
```